# Dynamic Class Type List Using Type C#

Tags: c#, generics

How can I dynamically initialize list of dynamic using C# Type.
I tried this but have been fail to set class as a type.

I am just reading a Datatable then creating a list of generic class.

**Example**

```
//Fetching assembly
  Type model = Type.GetType($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.Models.{className}");



     DataTable tbl = dataSet.Tables[0];
    List<model> genTbl = ConvertDataTable<model>(tbl);


   private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<T> data = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            T item = GetItem<T>(row);
            data.Add(item);
        }
        return data;
    }


    private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
    {
        Type temp = typeof(T);
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
            {
                if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                    pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

But this is wrong , please let me know how can I achieve this?

Also dynamic and object does not work because the generic method GetItem return nothing in case of object / dynamic.

**No Luck after updating.**

```
        //Fetching assembly
        Type model = Type.GetType($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.Models.{tblName}");

        Type elementType = typeof(List<>);
        Type typedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(List<string>())

        object listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typedListType);

        IList listInstanceAsIList = (IList)listInstance;

        List<model> genTbl = ConvertDataTable<model>(tbl);
```

Comment: And what for ?? Even if this would be possible you would not know the type at compile time so you will not be able to use methods/properties from element

Comment: I am creating dynamic jquery datatable for this I just send class name to controller than it select all record against table map with this class.

Comment: Can't you hard code the class instead of fetching it from an assembly?

Comment: Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(model );
            var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType); ?

Comment: @preciousbetine class name should dynamically create

Comment: [List<object> should work ...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRLr81) as in fact you don't care about the type

Comment: Do the possible types have anything in common? Then you could go for a common interface. Hard to tell without knowing **anything** about those types.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is: "this works with reflection". The actual question however is: **what are you trying to do with that list afterwards?** It will never be strongly typed, so all you get, e.g. when using `genericList[0]`, is an unspecified instance of `object`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method for how to call a ageneric method through reflection - which you have to do as you don´t know the actual type at **compile**-time.

Comment: I dont want to activate class to use its method

Comment: "Activate class"? What do you mean? Create an instance of it maybe? You won´t need to, as the method is static.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection in order to call your generic method with a type not known at compile-time. However you will **never** get a strongly typed list back from `ConvertDataTable`:

```
Type model = Type.GetType($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.Models.{className}");
DataTable tbl = dataSet.Tables[0];
MethodInfo method = typeWhereConvertDataTableIsDefined.GetMethod("ConvertDataTable");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(model);
var result = generic.Invoke(null, null);
```

`Invoke` however will return just an `object`. There´s no way at **compile**-time to turn this back to the actual `model`-type, which is only knwon at **runtime**.

So you can´t do much with that result, except casting it to `IList` or `IEnumerable` in order to iterate the elements (e.g. using a `foreach`):

```
var theList = (IList) result;
foreach(object o in theList)
    // DoSomething
```

Answer (score -1):

If the type of the elements is `dynamic` (the C# keyword), `List<dynamic>` is the most sensible option.

When you want to generate a list of a specific, known type, you can use reflection:

```
Type elementType = typeof(List<>);
Type typedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(yourTypeInstance);

object listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typedListType);

IList listInstanceAsIList = (IList)listInstance;
```

When you want a method to work with a list of any type, you could use generics instead, but that doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: it does not work please review the question again I have updated it

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The code above should work, and it is not in your updated question.

Comment: what is typedListType in this context?

Comment: The typed generic list type, so `List<string>` for example. In that case, `yourTypeInstance` would be `typeof(string)`.

Comment: And why not...?

Comment: There is nothing new in the question, so explain why this answer doesn't fit. Does it given an error? Something else?

Comment: you wrote listType.Makegeneric whereas type name is not hard coded in this case

Comment: What exactly is hardcoded in my answer? You can replace `yourTypeInstance` with the type you have in `model` now. So what is wrong with that?

Comment: And you asked for a list, you got one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198305/discussion-between-taha-sultan-temuri-and-patrick-hofman).

Comment: Let us continue on-site.

Comment: Update your question with your code merged with my answer.

Comment: What is your idea with `listType.MakeGenericType(List<string>())`? That should be `listType.MakeGenericType(model);`, as commented...